# Binding functions for pages loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery

I'm a little familiar with `jquery.on()` function to bind to events, similar to this:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".myclass", function() {
  $(this).customerFunction();   //or something like .tooltip()
  return this;
});
```

However, how do I bind this `customerFunction()` to whenever `.myclass` exists in the HTML, rather than just upon an event? I know I can do 
`$(".myclass").customerFunction();` for standard page loads, but it doesn't work if the page is loaded via ajax.

Cheers,

Comment: It would be much better if you used just one tooltip for all the elements you will be loading. I don't know if this plugin supports that, but qTip does.

Comment: The function here doesn't matter, I'll rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
$("[rel='tooltip']").on("mouseover", function() {
    $(this).tooltip();
    return this;
});
```

Comment: How is this going to work on elements loaded dynamically? I think you misunderstand how `on` works.

Comment: You are right. I don't think I'm using the correct function. jQuery.on() is for events, so I'm trying to figure out which function is the right one. I'm trying to bind .tooltip() to anytime rel='tooltip', or any class such as .class-name-1 appears in the HTML, regardless of whether it was loaded via ajax or not.

Comment: Hi Kapil, the issue isn't mouseover. I'm trying to bind the function to an element instead of an event.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a common mistake in jQuery selector

you need to quote `'tooltip'`

try `"[rel='tooltip']"`

Comment: You should better direct that at the OP, although I don't see how the manner the elements are inserted makes any difference at all.

Comment: The ajax is loaded using Rails Unobtrusive JavaScript, which simply calls jQuery's .ajax() function.

Answer (score 0):

Neverever gave me a good idea. I tried it and it worked!

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $('.myclass').customerFunction();  //or $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
  return this;
});
```